# Backup VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I want to backup a shutdown VirtualBox VM. When I export it as appliance in ova-format, are snapshots included then? Is it possible to go back to an older snapshot?

Is there a better way to make backups?

chris

Comment: Just backup all of the virtual machine data in question, its seperated by folders, so it should be easy.  Be sure to get the Virtual Box configuration file also.

Comment: Thank you. That works. There's a menu entry "add virtual machine". I didn't know that. But I think I have to use the same directory structure.